# call if(confirm) jquery/ajax more than once?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a ajax to delete one comment.
So before ajax deletes it I ask a confirmation.

The problem is, if user type CANCEL and after it he wants to delete the comment, the jquery will not work anymore. What is wrong?

```
var Progressajax2 = false;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".closeclass").on('click',function() {

        if(Progressajax2)
            return;
        Progressajax2 = true;

        var element = $(this);
        var I = element.attr("id");
        var value = element.attr("value");

        var pagecont = $('.pagecont'+value).val();
        var contcomments = $('.contcomments'+value).text();
        if(confirm('Are you sure?')) {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/delete.php",
                data: "id="+I,
                success: function() {
                    Progressajax2 = false;

                    pagecont = parseInt(pagecont)-parseInt(1);
                    contcomments = parseInt(contcomments)-parseInt(1);
                    $('.pagecont'+value).val(pagecont);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: seems to be fine...! what is the error in console if any?

Comment: Can you please provide the full code(at least the bind event)! Whatever you provided looks correct to me.

Comment: When you post code you should make sure that you use correct indenting, otherwise it is really hard understand the structure of the code.

Comment: looks like Progressajax2 is set to true and you don't set it to false.

Comment: oh, thank you friends! in fact, the progressajax is my problem!

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are setting `Progressajax2 = true;` before asking the confirmation.

Try it like this:

```
$(".closeclass").on('click', function () {
    if (Progressajax2 || !confirm('Are you sure?')) return;

    Progressajax2 = true;

    var element = $(this);
    var I = element.attr("id");
    var value = element.attr("value");

    var pagecont = $('.pagecont' + value).val();
    var contcomments = $('.contcomments' + value).text();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/delete.php",
        data: "id=" + I,
        success: function () {
            Progressajax2 = false;

            pagecont = parseInt(pagecont) - parseInt(1);
            contcomments = parseInt(contcomments) - parseInt(1);
            $('.pagecont' + value).val(pagecont);
        }
    });
});
```